# Card game "WAR" in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got a homework in school , it´s not required , but I want to do.

I have to create a game in php through array , but I dont know how to use. 
So i made begining, and I have problem with this, as you know , in the card game "War" , is don´t repeate same card, so I dont know how to use array_push or maybe array_pop? 
And then , how can I pair code with svg-img cards?

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' , "six" , "seven");
shuffle($arr);
$number = count($arr);

for ($x=6; $x < $number; $x++) { 
echo $arr[$x];   
}
```

Comment: Not sure what *game* you're developing but the initialization inside `for` loop is wrong, change `$x = 6` to `$x = 0`.

Comment: In material real, it´s game, when you play with somebody, and you have one half pack from all card, and another person have second pack. Then card is  interpreted , and one who has greater value card, wins. So, in PHP, can´t repeate same card, that has been already used. So I need to the number , that has been used, dont repeate.

Comment: *hmm*. Given your comment above, I've provided a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment,

> In material real, it´s game, when you play with somebody, and you have one half pack from all card, and another person have second pack. Then card is interpreted , and one who has greater value card, wins. So, in PHP, can´t repeate same card, that has been already used. So I need to the number , that has been used, dont repeate.

Hypothetically(just to give you an example), lets assume we have 6 cards of denomination 1 to 6. The **game solution** would be like this:

(Go through the comments below)

```
// Hypothetically, lets assume we have 6 cards of denomination 1 to 6
$cards = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

// Shuffle the cards
shuffle($cards);

// Count total number of cards
$number = count($cards);

// Give half of the cards to player 1 and half of the cards to Player 2
list($player1_cards, $player2_cards) = array_chunk($cards, $number / 2);

// Both the players started playing the game:
// Let say this game will be played based on randomness
for($i = 0; $i < $number / 2; ++$i){  // Number of rounds
    // Both the players draw a random card
    $player1_card_key = array_rand($player1_cards);
    $player2_card_key = array_rand($player2_cards);

    // Compare their denominations and check who won this round
    $output = $player1_cards[$player1_card_key] > $player2_cards[$player2_card_key] ? 'Player 1' : 'Player 2';
    echo $output . ' won this round. <br />';

    // Make sure that players don't use the same card again
    unset($player1_cards[$player1_card_key], $player2_cards[$player2_card_key]);
}
```

Here are the necessary references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Wow, thank you man. Im just the beginner , so I approximately know, what is what. So, thank you very much , you helped me . <3 ^^

Comment: But, how can I achieve that , the numbers not repeated? When the card lays out so it will not be used. There is some example of game : [WARGAME](https://cardgames.io/war/)

Comment: @Nol Please know that SO is not code writing service, and I've given *enough* information to give you a head start. Try to implement the game logic and if you get stuck at any point, feel free to ask on SO.